# reading and writing mulltiple images automatically in matlab?

Tags: matlab

i have 250 images stored at

> E:\HandVein_DataSet

these 250 images belong to 50 person , this mean each one has 5 images

these pictures are arranged as following

> 0001hv1-0001hv2-0001hv3-0001hv4-0001hv5 ....0002hv1-0002hv2-0002hv3-0002hv4-0002hv5 until 0050hv1-0050hv2-0050hv3-0050hv4-0050hv5

I want to read all these images and processing them according my steps and then saved the resultant images after preproceesing in a specific file,for example at E:\final result.

How can i do this in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the filenames are, e.g., `0001hv1.jpg` (you can change the extension as necessary).  You don't say what the output is; I'm assuming it's a modified version of the input image and that you want to use the same naming scheme.

```
in_dir = 'E:/Hand/Vein_DataSet';
out_dir = 'E:/final\ result';

for px = 1 : 50,
    for hx = 1 : 5,
      fname = sprintf('%04dhv%d.jpg', px, hx);  
      current_image = imread(fullfile(in_dir, fname));

      % do processing
      out_image = some_function(current_image);

      % save output
      imwrite(out_image, fullfile(out_dir, fname));
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks alot for your help, i tried to implement it and the result was                                                                    ??? Error using ==> imwrite at 378
      Too few input arguments

Comment: Woops!  I forgot to add the image as an argument.  I have edited the answer; the important part is that the imwrite line is now `imwrite(out_image, fullfile(out_dir, fname));`

Comment: ok , thanks i don't know how can i thank you .i tried the code after modification but there is a problem , matlab implemented the code and saved in the final results folder all images until 0032hv2 and then wait and do nothing , why this occures , and how can i manipulate this error. my regards.

Comment: There are so many things that could be going wrong there that it's almost impossible to troubleshoot.  I would suspect that it is a problem with your image processing or issues with the files themselves.  You can rule in/out the former by simply doing `out_image = current_image`.  Trying to mannually handle the specific file that it hangs on could tell you something about what's going on.  If this has solved your initial problem, then you should accept the answer and start a new question that's specific to the problem you're now seeing.

Comment: i am not only accept your answer , but also ask god to protect you, also i found when i implement the code manually on the image 0032hv3,the code not work , the figure opens without image to be displayed.now i have only one question, i want some simple illustration on "'%04dhv%d" that you use what do you mean by '%04d $$ %d?

Comment: Thanks :)  The `%04d` and `%d` are printf-style format specifiers - see http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html.  I know the documentation is kind of dense, so, roughly: `%d` means integer (i.e., convert a 1 into a "1" as opposed to "1.0") and `%04d` means an integer with leading zeros so that the whole thing is 4 characters (i.e., convert 1 to "0001", 12 to "0012", 123 to "0123", 1234 to "1234", etc).  This reference for the c version might help, too - they're very similar:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/